# Given base $b$ what is the expected value of round off error in rounding to $d$ digits?

Tags: probability, numerical-methods, expected-value, approximation, computational-mathematics

Given base $b$, what is the expected value of round off error (relative, not absolute) when we round $x$ to $d$ digits, where $x$ is a random variable?  Assume $x$ is drawn from a uniform distribution over an interval.

It's easy to determine maximum error: e.g. for $b = 10, d = 1$, it's $1/3$, which occurs at $15$.  The expected value requires integrating over the floor function and seems to require using the harmonic series.

Comment: "It's easy to determine maximum error: e.g. for $b = 10, d = 1$, it's $1/3$, which occurs at $15$" : Is this a typo, or am I misunderstanding your intent?  Integers in the half open interval $~10 \leq n < 20~$ all have 2 digits, not 1 digit.

Comment: I assume the question talks about rounding to $d$ significant digits. So $150$ would also be an extrem case, rounded to $100$.

Comment: @user2661923 Edited to clarify that Ingix is correct.